# Is there any way to install Ubuntu 20.04 on iMac 5.1 late 2006?

Tags: boot, grub2, mac

I've been trying to revive an old imac for a few days now, there are a few articles describing how to install 64-bit Ubuntu on a 32bit EFI system. I was able to make bootable USB installer stick based on [this](https://mesom.de/efi32boot/index.html) article. There were a few tries of installing, the cleanest install was with preinstalling `grub-efi-ia32` package. The installation went without any errors and I was able to boot to grub without any external drives. At this moment I'm stuck and not sure where to go next. After grub tries to load Ubuntu my imac is stuck on black screen, I also tried `nomodeset` option which helped me to load from my USB drive, but it didn't help me with booting to my install.
I don't need to dual-boot, I just want to run Ubuntu.
Also I did use lvm when installing, although I'm having doubts that it should be used in this particular setup.
Any advises or help is appreciated.

update: after some tinkering with chroot and installing openssh server on my machine I was able to ssh into my system. Basically everything is working except xorg, apparently my videocard is missing its ROM/Driver, although xorg man page tells that my gpu(RV530/x1600) is supported.

My X log have this records:

```
[KMS] drm report modesetting isn't supported.
```

And my kernel log:

```
[drm:radeon_get_bios [radeon]] *ERROR* Unable to locate a BIOS ROM
```

Still need help, reading a lot of forums and articles couldn't help me solving this.

Comment: You cannot install any 64-bit Operating System on any 32-bit hardware. Try a 32-bit version of Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Check to make sure CPU is only 32bit, might be 64bit with a 32bit OS installed.

Comment: CPU on my imac is 64-bit Core2Duo T7400, but EFI is 32-bit. I can boot to 64-bit liveusb ubuntu or other 64-bit OS with no problem if I modify the bootloader correctly.

Answer (score 1):

So I've finally made it work by installing it from eternal dvd drive (internal seems to be working but it wasn't accepting my dvds). I took the 16.04 image from Matt Gadient's website burned it, loaded it with the help of rEFInd, installed the OC and upgraded right to 20.04. Got a few bugs with gdm3: login screen is a distorted mess and my standard backgrounds are just a black color, but rather than that everything works pretty good for almost 15 years old computer.